# Can I hide my superclass from the users of my class?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

Is it possible to encapsulate the fact that my class is derived from a certain superclass? Something like:

```
@class NoneOfYourBusiness;
@interface MyClass : NoneOfYourBusiness
@end
```

The compiler doesn’t like this: *Attempting to use the forward class 'NoneOfYourBusiness' as superclass of 'MyClass'*.

Comment: The compiler has to see the makeup of the superclass. Could you create a dummy superclass whose header you import, and then `isa`-swizzle instances when you create them?

Comment: Thank you! Swizzling would be too much magic for my purposes, though, as I’m just trying to hide some implementation details. The compiler already knows how to get class information from multiple sources (like properties redefined in a class extension), so I was hoping for some short trick of that kind.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some indirection; a dummy superclass in the inheritance tree, between `MyClass` and `RealSuperclass`:

Private header, HiddenSuperclass.h, with corresponding implementation file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HiddenSuper : NSObject

- (void)makePancakes;

@end
```

Header for dummy class, corresponding empty implementation

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "HiddenSuper.h"

@interface DummySuper : HiddenSuper
// Nothing to see here, folks!
@end
```

Then your public class's header:

```
#import "DummySuper.h"

@interface PublicSubclass : DummySuper

- (void)fixBreakfast;

@end
```

And the implementation, hidden by compilation:

```
#import "PublicSubclass.h"
#import "HiddenSuper.h"

@implementation PublicSubclass

- (void)fixBreakfast
{
    [self makePancakes];
}

@end
```

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for... I'm not clear on what hiding this actually buys you.

Answer (score 0):

Two answers

---

The requirement makes no sense. Client code can see the super class does not mean anything because it should be empty.

i.e. Thats all they can see

```
@interface NoneOfYourBusiness : NSObject
@end
@interface MyClass : NoneOfYourBusiness
- (void)publicMethod;
@end
```

because you should put all private / internal method / variable in private header / implementation file.

---

Ok you really need to hide it for some reason, then hide everything

public header

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
- (void)publicMethod;
@end
```

private header / implementation file

```
@interface NoneOfYourBusiness : NSObject
@end

@interface MyClassImpl : NoneOfYourBusiness
- (void)publicMethod;
@end

@interface MyClass ()
@property (strong) MyClassImpl *impl;
@end
@implementation
- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    return self.impl;
}
@end
```

you can even make `MyClass` inherited from `NSProxy` to make it a real proxy object